# Positioning texts in the footer

Tags: html, css, center, inline, footer

I want my footer to contain 2 parts of text: the first short text should be centered according to my main, the second text (the current date) should be aligned to the right side of main. Both texts should be in one line. I would also like to change the position of the date on a smaller screen. So that both texts are centered and in two different lines on smartphones and tablets. (I use the foundation framework.) 
All i got is this:

HTML:

```
<footer class="centered"> 
    <span class="block">
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span id="date" class="block rightside">
        <script>
            n = new Date();
            y = n.getFullYear();
            m = n.getMonth() + 1;
            d = n.getDate();
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d + "." + m + "." + y;
        </script>
    </span>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
.centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.rightside {
    float: right;
}
```

The problem is, that float isn't responsive in my case. On a certain screen size the right text goes to the next line, but is out of my main.
I'm quite new to html and css, so is there a better way to arrange these elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CSS media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to accomplish this task.

What you will do is specify a width at which you want to change the CSS rules, and then you'll set those rules. Here is one I think will work for you with the markup you have:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .block {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Basically, we are resetting the styles to get things to center on two lines as you'd like.

First, we reset the display style from `inline-block` to `block` so that they'll show on two lines. Then, we remove the float on the date to get it to act normally. The `text-align` property you already have on the `footer` will take care of the centering for us.

You can adjust the 800px value to any value you'd like, and you don't have to use pixels. You can use `ems` or whatever else.

**Edit:**
To truly center the middle span and not have it be pushed over by the date, one option is to use a different method to move the date to the right, which would be to absolutely position it. This will take it out of the normal flow of the document, so that it doesn't push the other span. Then, in your media query, you can move it back to standard positioning.

For example:

```
.block.rightside {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px; /* or whatever */
    bottom: 10px; /* or whatever */
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .block.rightside {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

You could also adjust the position of the centered span, instead, perhaps with relative position or a negative right margin.

Comment: First of all, thank u for ur answer! Unfortunately it didn't work. Here is my code now:

Comment: (at)media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em) {.block {
 display: block;
    float: none;
 } }  (at) media screen and (min-width: 64em) { .block {
 display: inline-block;
} 
}               I dont know why it doesnt work actually. Ur answer seemed to be logical. Another problem i have is, that the right text influences the other so the first text isnt centered really. It's like the right text works as a new border, instead of the right side of main. Do u have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: See edit about fixing the true centering issue. But other than that, to help more, I'd need you to explain what about it doesn't work, and also to include a reproduceable code sample in your post. You will likely need to include a basic version of your overall page HTML rather than only the footer markup, and you'd also need to include any other styles in your CSS that may be affecting the footer. One problem I do see with your media query, though, is that there is a 0.0025em range where neither query will apply. Also, don't include a space between "@" and "media" in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

I read your issue and I think there are a few things going on. First let's tackle the big picture.

What you are delving into is responsive web design and so you will need to learn about media queries and what goes into their use. Media queries are how you target certain screen size ranges. A media query is what is needed here.

Bringing things into a more focused view, I would say that you actually don't need to float your "rightside" class div right. Generally speaking, if the end result is supposed to look sort of like you have put the two areas of text into columns, you actually want to float left. I have found floating things right in these situations look good or correct for the initial answer or as a "quick fix", but once you dive deeper into things, there are always some problems caused.

With all of that said as an introduction said, let me now try and provide a possible solution for your issue, with the understanding that in code there are often more than one way to accomplish something. Here is my way...

Basic idea: I would create a div that has 3 divs (essentially 3 columns) inside of it that are formatted in a row. I would leave the left div empty, the middle div would have text and the div on the right would have text. I would use media queries to reposition the divs as needed for certain screen sizes. So...

Step 1) I would create a container div inside the footer div. Then I would create 3 divs inside of that, with equal dimensions. Refer to code below. Oh and make sure that you put this code in the "head" section of your html...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

OK, now the footer code I would use...

**HTML**

```
<footer class="centered"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div id="col1">
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <span class="block">
                Text 1
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="col3">
            <span id="date" class="block rightside">
                <script>
                    n = new Date();
                    y = n.getFullYear();
                    m = n.getMonth() + 1;
                    d = n.getDate();
                    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d + "." + m + 
                    "." + y;
                </script>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Regarding the styling, there are two things to consider. How things will look on a computer screen and how things will look on a mobile device. Notice how I used the pseudo class of "container:after" to have the columns behave as is needed. If you want to see what would happen if you didn't include that, simply comment that part out and you'll notice why that part is so important. Also notice the setting changes in the Media Query section and what they affect...

**CSS** *(Please notice that I included background colors for all the divs. That is so that you can see what is happening as you change the size of the screen. You can get rid of the colors and also align the text inside the divs as needed.)*

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
} 

#col1, #col2, #col3 {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
}

/* ========== MEDIA QUERIES ========== */

@media screen and (max-width: 1997px) {
    #col1 {
        display: none;
    }

    #col2, #col3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And there you have it. That is how I personally would accomplish what I believe you are looking to do. Again, I didn't align the text... the main thing to correct was how you were orientating your divs.

I hope that helps and please remember what I said... That is only how I would have done it. I'm sure there are different or even better ways.

Good Luck!  :)

Comment: Oh...I forgot to write "Step 2"! Well, "Step 2" was what the CSS code is, so I didn't actually skip anything.  :)

Comment: Oh MAN!!!!! I also have a typo. Im losing it today! Here is the correction:

/*========== MEDIA QUERIES ========== */

@media screen and (max-width: 1297px) {
 #col1 {
  display: none;
 }

 #col2, #col3 {
  width: 100%;
 }
}